# Can you help me in this line of codding?

Tags: php, html

```
echo '<div id="result"> ".$titulo."<br>".$descricao." <br> <img src='".$imagem."'> <br>".$data."<br> </div>';
```

`$imagem` is a link to an image.
I want to run this query, but I get an error around this line of code.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing quotes,

```
echo "<div id='result'>".$titulo."<br>".$descricao." <br> <img src='".$imagem."'>   <br>".$data."<br> </div>";
```

Read: *[PHP Strings!!](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)*

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
echo '<div id="result"> '.$titulo.'<br>'.$descricao.' <br> <img src="'.$imagem.'"> <br>'.$data.'<br></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sprintf instead.

```
echo sprintf  ('<div id="result"> %s<br>%s <br> <img src="%s"> <br>%s<br> </div>', $titulo, $descricao, $imagem, $data );
```

Answer (score 1):

This must work, you must pay attention to your `'` and `"`:

```
echo '<div id="result">'.$titulo.'"<br>"'.$descricao.'" <br> <img src="'.$imagem.'"> <br>"'.$data.'"<br> </div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

```
echo  '<div id="result"> '.$titulo.'<br>'.$descricao.' <br> <img src="'.$imagem.'"> <br>'.$data.'<br> </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mixed up this: ' and this: "

```
ECHO '<div id="result">' . $titulo . '<br>' . $descricao . '<br><img src="' . $imagem. '"><br>' . $data . '<br> </div>';
```

I hope I got everything correct with the apostrophes. If you open with a single apostrophe then you have to use it everywhere, you can also use ", but then you have to flag the inner HTML Apostrophes like this:

```
ECHO "<div id=\"result\">" . $titulo . "<br>" . $descricao . "<br><img src=\"" . $imagem. "\"><br>" . $data . "<br> </div>";
```